# How to disable Thermal Shutdown

Tags: 12.04, suspend, hibernate

It's not that I want to totally disable thermal protection, but instead of instantly turn-off the machine, how can I make my Ubuntu 12.04 sleep or hibernate instead. As a programmer my IDE and project breaks when closed improperly.

Is there a solution to hibernate or sleep when thermal peak is reached?

**Update:**

The laptop I have does not thermal shutdown at random times, it shutdowns when I am compiling (Java app), when CPU usage is at max, when just browsing the internet no problem, so the problem is with the hardware. It does not happen everytime, I just want that when it happens it will just hibernate or sleep.

Comment: Why not fix the thermal problem (that would be my option since overheating is bad enough for hardware)? Did you install proprietary driver for the graph card? If not ... install `lm-sensors`, check temps, install prop. driver, check temps.

Comment: And I know how to turn it off but I have not found a method to let it do a hibernate. You probably need to do this by yourself with a script and cron. And to the downvoters: why not educate and explain why it is bad?!

Comment: @Rinzwind I will update my question with this, the laptop I have does not thermal shutdown at random times, it shutdowns when I am compiling, when CPU usage is at max, when just browsing the internet no problem, so the problem is with the hardware. It does not happen everytime, I just want that when it happens it will just hibernate or sleep.

Comment: i think thermal shutdown is completely hardware handled. The processor is hardwired to kill the power in case of overheating and the os has no control over it. u better clean the vent and prevent overheating in the first place

Comment: @Meow I know, but how does Windows do the trick, my laptop is dual-boot when I am in windows then its "about" to overheat it will sleep. So that time I know its hot already, so I will go out and make it cool for couple of minutes :-)

Comment: "sudo apt-get install fancontrol lm-sensors i2c-tools" followed by "sudo detect-sensors" to find the availabe sensors and add them to the mod for the script u write to solve to work

Comment: Another approach is to use a CPU frequency profiler/controller, there are some desktop plugins in repo like `indicator-cpufreq`

Comment: @Meow I already have the GUI Psensor which monitors CPU temperature with chart. Are you recommending I write my own script to hibernate on temperature rise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long time I have the answer:

```
#!/bin/bash

# PURPOSE: Script to check temperature of CPU cores and report/shutdown if specified temperatures exceeded
#
# AUTHOR: feedback[AT]HaveTheKnowHow[DOT]com

# Expects two arguments:
# 1. Warning temperature
# 2. Critical shutdown temperature
# eg. using ./CPUTempShutdown.sh 30 40
# will warn when temperature of one or more cores hit 30degrees and shutdown when either hits 40degrees.

# NOTES:
# Change the strings ">>/home/xybrek" as required
# Substitute string "myemail@myaddress.com" with your own email address in the string which starts "/usr/sbin/ssmtp myemail@myaddress.com"

# Assumes output from sensors command is as follows:
#
# coretemp-isa-0000
# Adapter: ISA adapter
# Core 0: +35.0 C (high = +78.0 C, crit = +100.0 C) 
#
# coretemp-isa-0001
# Adapter: ISA adapter
# Core 1: +35.0 C (high = +78.0 C, crit = +100.0 C) 
#
# if not then modify the commands str=$(sensors | grep "Core $i:") & newstr=${str:14:2} below accordingly

echo "JOB RUN AT $(date)"
echo "======================================="

echo ''
echo 'CPU Warning Limit set to => '$1
echo 'CPU Shutdown Limit set to => '$2
echo ''
echo ''

sensors

echo ''
echo ''
stop=0
while true;
do
sleep 1.5
for i in 0 1
do
str=$(sensors | grep "Core $i:")
newstr=${str:17:2}

if [[ ${newstr} -ge $1 ]]
then
echo '============================' >>/home/xybrek/Desktop/CPUWarning.Log
echo $(date) >>/home/xybrek/Desktop/CPUWarning.Log
echo '' >>/home/xybrek/Desktop/CPUWarning.Log
echo ' WARNING: TEMPERATURE CORE' $i 'EXCEEDED' $1 '=>' $newstr >>/home/xybrek/Desktop/CPUWarning.Log
echo '' >>/home/xybrek/Desktop/CPUWarning.Log
echo '============================' >>/home/xybrek/Desktop/CPUWarning.Log
fi

if [[ ${newstr} -ge $2 ]]
then
echo '============================'
echo ''
echo 'CRITICAL: TEMPERATURE CORE' $i 'EXCEEDED' $2 '=>' $newstr
echo ''
echo '============================'
sudo pm-suspend
echo 'Sleeping....'
#exit
else
echo ' Temperature Core '$i' OK at =>' $newstr
echo ''
fi
done
done

echo 'Both CPU Cores are within limits'
echo ''
```

Comment: Could I ask why sudo in `sudo pm-suspend` as I think the whole script should run as root. So it will not ask/wait for password at that critical stat.